# AngularJS - Location aware ng-view navigation using TweenMax

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ng-animate, ng-view

I am a complete noob to AngularJS and have started building my first project and have been hitting obstacles every step of the way...

I'm trying to build something very simple, here's the gist of what i'm trying to achieve:

- I have 5 pages/views that get pulled in and created using JSON data based on this article - blog.brunoscopelliti.com/how-to-defer-route-definition-in-an-angularjs-web-app. Which is wired into a factory. getJSON()

  ```
  function($route, $location, $http, $q) {

  var jsonLoaded = {}; 

  jsonLoaded.getJSON = function() {

      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http.get('pages.json').success(function(data) {
          deferred.resolve(data);
      }).error(function() {
          deferred.reject();
      });
      return deferred.promise;
  }
  return jsonLoaded;
  ```
- When navigating through the views, I would like to have a hierarchical carousel transition effect.
  i.e. if your on index 0, clicking index 1, would navigate from right to left and clicking back on index 0 would then navigate the view from left to right etc. This is conditionalised in the animate.js file(s) in my plunks using hasClass().

I have tried 3 main options with separate plunks:

**Option 1** using ng-click to add class - http://plnkr.co/edit/0mrebo8BMlrz1YkttxsT?p=preview

```
$scope.navDirection = function(pageClass) {
    $scope.pageTransClass = pageClass;
};
```

- This yields the best result, and navigates exactly as I want, the problem then is when clicking the browser back or forward button, the class remains the same which is also expected.
- Adds/changes the class for both enter and leave views.

**Option 2** using $routeProvider resolve - http://plnkr.co/edit/SPfgKUyYt7LMQITHzj2I?p=preview

```
resolve: {
   direction: ["changePageDirection",
       function(changePageDirection) {
           return changePageDirection.direction($route.current.params.pageId, $routeParams.pageId);
       }
   ]
}
```

- This produces a delay when adding the Classes, i.e. only really starts to work on the 3rd nav item click.
- This method seams to add/change the Class to the "enter" animation, but the "leave" still keeps the old Class.

**Option 3** using Observe - http://plnkr.co/edit/TwtkGrY1Ww4uYY8n2LO5?p=preview

```
return function(scope, element, attrs) {

    attrs.$observe("pageDirectionObs", function (value) {
        if (value) {
            element.addClass(value);
        }
    });
};
```

- This like Option 2 only really starts to work on the 3rd click.
- This method seams to add/change the class of the "enter" animation, but the "leave" still keeps the old Class.

I'm beginning to think that my main problem is either understanding (or lack thereof) of $scope and the way in which AngularJS compiles everything.

I have been at this for weeks now and am no where closer to where i need to be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

- Here is a 4th example using ui-view and ui-view-extras
- Here is the plunk - embed.plnkr.co/vjSBLzMMKIrkHD7sOctN/preview

Comment: Any suggestions, from anyone???

Comment: I'll take a stab in the dark here, I have noticed that the last direction chosen is the direction the transition occurs when clicking the browser buttons. At a guess it could be either a caching issue or the promise hasn't resolved before the transition occurs. You could try changing the class for the required transition before the transition occurs external of a promise. I'll have another look tomorrow for you if you haven't resolved the issue before hand.

Comment: That's correct for the 1st example (the one that attaches the class to the view using ng-click), this produces the closest end result to what i'm looking for (i.e attaches the class to both the entering and leaving views). As the other examples attach the class to the view, but only the target view and not the previous one (i.e. the one leaving the DOM). I have a created a 4th attempt using ui-router and ui-router-extras. But again am only able to effect the class on the view that is entering and not the one that is leaving.

Comment: Here is a link to a screen shot - http://postimg.org/image/apd92vw63/, so how would i change classes on both the entering and leaving views before the transition?

Comment: Hey lawless, i checked your post on freelancer.. ping me on skype for further conversation - skype : multipurposesynsoft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was actually fairly simple. Instead of changing the class for each direction I attached a variable to $rootScope, which changes prior to any page transition and based the animation off the $rootScope variable instead of the class.